# CountDownTimer not working after few minutes past screen locked

Tags: android, countdowntimer

[image]

I got a ListView in which Multiple Items and each item will have a duration.

When I click on Start button, i have to start from item1, after Completing that particular duration I have to increment the counter and insert it into database and move to next item.

My problem is that, when I lock the screen and after like 20 minutes, the data is not getting inserted to database.

Comment: That's because your app is killed by the OS. You probably need a `JobDispatcher` or something similar which start the app process, periodically check the amount of time remained to complete the task, re-schedule itself and proceed to the next one.

Comment: my code has to work until the user clicks on stop button

Comment: You can't run your code for hours with the screen locked, the system kills your app at some point to save battery. You need something which runs periodically in the background, check [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)